# Sorting Multiple data regions-SSRS

Tags: sql-server, sorting, reporting-services, calculated-field

I have a report that contains  data from Multiple datasets (using lookup),indicators and report item fields. I would like to use one for of  sort to sort all the  columns in asc or desc order.

1. Product ID (Dataset 1)
2. Sales of Wk1 (Dataset 1)
3. Sales of Wk2 (Dataset 1)
4. Sum of sales(sum of report item 2 and 3)
5. Cost (lookup dataset 2)
6. Profit (report item 4-5)
7. Profit% (indicator)

How can I sort all this using say profit - lowest profit or negative profit first.
Is there a way to do this is in ssrs

Comment: Could you please share what have you tried? Otherwise, an `order by` should do it.

Comment: I tried sorting Profit in Z to A . In the product ID field I added tablix sort using Profit from Z to A. Throwing error - report item in Sort not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your tablix, and click the Sorting tab. Add an expression for each level of sorting, based on the same expressions you have listed. From there you can select Ascending or Descending order for each sort expression.

Comment: If that's the only option I will try it, but my formula are  are elaborate switch conditions and  look ups. Trying to avoid this method or keep as last option.

Comment: Try it. I always use this method and have never noticed a performance issue, even when my sort expressions use custom code.